# Strange behaviour of my computer. Maybe some defect hardware?

Tags: hardware-failure, desktop-computer

I really need your assistance and I hope that you can help me.

I bought a new computer about 1 month ago (assembled it on my own, just bought all parts).
For about 2 weeks there were no errors/bsods nothing it just ran perfectly.
After these 2 weeks(or maybe 3 weeks idk) my computer began to crash sometimes with a bsod saying "pfn_list_corrupt".
I googled it and I read that a possible cause could be my RAM. So I replaced my ram but nothing changed at all.
I also scanned both ram kits (2x4gb corsair vengeance) with memtest86+ and both I got errors for both kits. it is a 1600 ram running at 1,5v so I looked up my bios settings and changed the ram voltage from 1.510V to 1.500V and scanned the ram again.
And again errors were listed but at different points/tests.

I decided not to replace any more hardware but to just work as usual with my computer.
Sometimes it runs for 2-3 days without any problems but sometimes it crashed every 5 minutes.

Now since about 3-4 days the behaviour got even worse. New bsods (system_exception, memory_management), more crashes and strange temperature sensor behaviour.
Because of the warm weather here I started to watch how much hotter my system gets while doing some heavy work (prime95).
So I started CpuID Hardwaremonitor and watched the cpu temperature. I noticed that the temperature fluctuates from 17 degrees celcius to 30 degress celsius in just 5-6 seconds. Sometimes the temperature shoots up to 30 D.C. and then it calms down to 16-17 D.C. and then it shoots up again....
Usually my cpu temperature was at about 28 D.C while idleing.

I started to use different OS (Win7, Win8, Linux Arch, Linux Kubunutu).
The problems described above happended running W7.
I wasn't able to install W8 because it started crashing while initializing hardware after installation.
Until now I didn't notice any crashes under Linux Arch + Awesome window manager.
Sometimes the X server crashes running Kubuntu.

I really don't know what happens to my computer. First I thought it is just the memory. Yesterday I thought the new errors could be caused by the heat but I think it is the mainboard (Gigabyte GA-970A-DS3). 
Are there maybe any hints in my description that can tell anyone of you what the problem is or what it could be?
At the moment I can't go to a computer shop because our car is broken (maybe I can tomorrow) so I hope that someone here at SU can help me in the meanwhile.

Thanks in advance :)

P.S.: My hardware configuration:

AMD FX6300 6Core (not overclocked)
Gigabyte GA-970A-DS3
4x4GB Corsair Vengeance LP CML8GX3M2A1600C9
Palit Nvidia GeForce GTX660
Samsung 840 Series Basic SSD (120GB)

Comment: Tried with only one of the memory modules in at a time? If the board has onboard graphics, I'd also pull the card. Basically reduce it to the minimum number of components needed to work and try your memory testing from there. Also worth trying a firmware update, but you'd want the system to be stable before doing that.

Comment: @Skadier What exactly do you mean by "30 D.C" never heard of a temperature measurement like that. In the end you need to resolve your memory errors. I would adjust the voltage on the memory, I am going to guess, you purchase memory not designed for the   motherboard.  1.5V is really high for type of hardware you have.

Comment: Yes D.C. means degrees celsius.
I checked the ram voltage at corsair.com and it says that it was tested with 1.5V. I forgot to mention that I increased the voltage by 0.01V (from 1.5V to 1.51V) because I am using all four ram banks(google said that it might help if all banks are full to increase ram voltage). I'll try what happens if I use only one ram at a time because I haven't tried that yet. thanks to all of you :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a defective motherboard if RAM is failing memtest and you've replaced it already. If the RAM slots are bad then it would cause what are experiencing. I would RMA the board for a replacement.